# How to force terminate std::thread by TerminateThread()?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I called [IMFSourceReader::ReadSample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfreadwrite/nf-mfreadwrite-imfsourcereader-readsample) and I found it was stuck if it cannot read data.

So I tried to terminate the thread by TerminateThread() but it returned 0 as a fail.

How could I terminate the stuck thread?

This is my sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class MyObject
{
private:
    ...

    std::thread *t;
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::thread::native_handle_type handle;

    int getsample(uint8_t* data)
    {
        // call a ReadSample
        hr = pVideoReader->ReadSample(
              MF_SOURCE_READER_ANY_STREAM,    // Stream index.
              0,                              // Flags.
              &streamIndex,                   // Receives the actual stream index. 
              &flags,                         // Receives status flags.
              &llTimeStamp,                   // Receives the time stamp.
              &pSample                        // Receives the sample or NULL.
        );

        ...

        return 0;
    }
    int myfunc_wrapper(uint8_t* data)
    {
        int ret = 0;
        BOOL bpass = 0;

        if (t == nullptr) {
            t = new std::thread([this, &data, &ret]()
                {
                    ret = this->getsample(data);
                    this->cv.notify_one();
                });
            handle = t->native_handle();
            t->detach();
        }

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(this->m);

            if (this->cv.wait_for(l, 2500ms) == std::cv_status::timeout) {
                bpass = TerminateThread(handle, 0);
                if (bpass == 0) {
                    std::cout << "TerminateThread Fail! " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
                }
                throw std::runtime_error("Timeout Fail 2500 ms");
            }
        }

        delete t;
        t = nullptr;
    }

public:

    int my_func(uint8_t* raw_data)
    {
        bool timedout = false;

        try {
            if (myfunc_wrapper(raw_data) != 0)
                return -1;
        }
        catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
            timedout = true;
        }

        if (timedout)
            return -1;

        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    uint8_t data[512];
    MyObject* obj = new MyObject();

    while (true)
    {
        obj->my_func(data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
TerminateThread Fail! 6
Timeout Fail 2500 ms
TerminateThread Fail! 6
Timeout Fail 2500 ms
...
```

I also tried to use pthread_cancel but it cannot be compiled because there is a type error.

> no suitable constructor exists to convert from "std::thread::native_handle_type" to "__ptw32_handle_t"

```
      handle = t->native_handle();
...
      pthread_cancel(handle); // no suitable constructor exists to convert
```

Comment: NEVER terminate threads. Allow them to cooperatively end what they are doing

Comment: Aside: there's not much point keeping a pointer to a detached thread around to leak each time you throw.

Comment: Have you considered what happens if `this->cv.notify_one();` happens before `this->cv.wait_for(l, 2500ms) == std::cv_status::timeout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it failed to terminate is that the native handle is no longer valid after detaching, one way you could do this is to `OpenThread` using the thread id to get a new handle.

To get the thread id, you could use its handle before detaching like this:

```cpp
DWORD nativeId = GetThreadId(t->native_handle());
t->detach();
```

After that, just open a new handle to the thread to terminate it:

```cpp
HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_TERMINATE, FALSE, nativeId);
if (hThread)
{
    BOOL result = TerminateThread(hThread, 0);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
}
```

But you should **not** do this, consider other ways to signal the thread to terminate on its own.

Comment: Thanks! It can work despite it causing access violations in my thread.